# Convert gadget from solar charging to wired charging

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics, charging

I have one of these [ultrasonic pest repellents](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GLYYL92).

The gadget is powered by solar power, but I live in an area that does not receive enough sunlight to power the thing well. I was thinking to convert the repellent from solar power to a wired DC input to charge the battery pack.

If there is already a controller in place charging the battery pack from the solar cell, is it as simple as wiring in a port to plug in USB? Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

Comment: wait ... cats are pests?

Comment: When they come into your yard uninvited, start fighting with each other at 3am, and make everything dirty....yes.

Comment: @Brian-Drummond: Yes. Or at least, other people's cats are, and I don't have any.

Comment: Hey, So Im aware of the product you're using. If you open up the setup, youll see a link of the panel into a preliminary regulator. Just desolder it or keep it and jack it with a DC supply and if the current ratings mismatch, try using those cheap buck coverters. 

Edit: The preliminary does a fairly decent job in regulating current but not when your DC jack is pushing out 1A or more current. So hence the buck converter.

Comment: Yes. power supply of same voltage as PV panel SHOULD work. Panel is 6V (12 cells) so probably a LiIon battery. You COULD use a LiIon charger but the internal charger should work OK. If it IS LiIon battery you could remove battery and power from 3.5 to 4V supply. DO NOT use a power supply (rather than a LiIon charger) directly connected to a LiIon battery .

Comment: Does the device actually work? What 'pests' does it keep away?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon it did a pretty good job on the cats, I have camera footage of them seeing the device and clearly not liking it.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the 4 NiMH batteries are in series; they probably are.

If they are, you need 4 x 1.2V = 4.8V; 5V should work. You could remove the solar panel and batteries, and connect the 5 V and ground of a USB cable to the plus and minus outputs of the empty battery holder. Check if the USB outlet you are going to use can deliver enough current for your gadget before connecting it.

Keeping the rechargeable batteries is trickier to do; you would have to find out how the batteries are charged, and if 5 V will do to charge them far enough, or at least trickle charge them. The solar panel could be delivering more than 5 V, and the charging method and IC, if any, are unknown.

Or get a Boxer, I have found they are really good at keeping cats out of the garden.

Comment: This is what the listing says it is powered by.  3. Power Supply: 4*2/3AA Ni-MH rechargeable batteries.

4. Power Consumption: working=15mA standby≤10uA

Comment: NiMH? Didn't see that coming. Will try to edit answer.

Comment: The listing also said it had 3 AA batteries inside.  The only way to be sure is to open it up and have a look.

Comment: Yes. 3 NiMH is 3.6V; up to about 4.5V when charging, so 5V from the USB would be a bit much; no guarantees that would work. If I understand you correctly, the listing says it has 4 NiMH batteries, but also says it has 3?

Comment: Most experts in Google say that ultrasonic pest repellers Do Not Work and there are no truthful tests that show them working. Some make NO Ultrasonic noises (the manufacturers hope that you might believe their lies).